# Django: How to exclude login from accounts url?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm using django v1.8

I have my login mechanism.

views.py

```
def login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    print 'username=', username
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
    print 'user=', user

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        #user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        print 'login'
        return redirect('eReg.views.modules')

    else:
        print 'no login'
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

In `urls.py` I'm also using `accounts` for resetting and changing password. Is there a way to excluding `accounts/login` and use mine? Because when I'm using `{% urls 'login' %}` it redirects me to `accounts/login` which is not supported in my application.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    url(r'^login/', 'eReg.views.login', name='login'),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

)
```

Comment: use `url(r'^accounts/login/', 'eReg.views.login', name='login'),`

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool Great! I must have both in `urls.py`: url(r'^login/', 'eReg.views.login', name='login'), url(r'^accounts/login/', 'eReg.views.login', name='login'),

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool Please add it as an answer to accept it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **urls.py**

replace

```
url(r'^login/', 'eReg.views.login', name='login'),
```

with

```
url(r'^accounts/login/', 'eReg.views.login', name='login'),
```

like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    url(r'^accounts/login/', 'eReg.views.login', name='login'),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

)
```

This will call your customized view.